# Issues about placing controls out of the form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to know if is a problem for my users, me, stability, or my VB .NET program when controls like textbox, development buttons or dev tools are placed out of the form body (by extand for using tools, and reduce before publishing).

Controls are enabled = false, or hidden but necessary for my program run flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a technique that used to be common, and even today I'm not aware of anything about it that will actually break anything: winforms is perfectly happy to let you position items out of the visible area.

But it's a little unusual to see anymore, because we have better tools for managing this.

I'll add a note about remembering to call `SuspsendLayout()` before changing a bunch of controls to reduce flickering, and `ResumeLayout()` when finished.

Comment: I take the note ;) so, what do you want to mean with better tools ?

Comment: And see anymore ? ahaha (:

Comment: Use `.Visible`, add/remove to the forms `Controls` collection, place them into a groupbox or even custom control that can be shown/hidden, use a data driven layout mode...